# image background / foreground detection with ccv

Tags: image, image-processing, canvas, computer-vision

I need to programmatically determine the best place to overlay text on an image. In other words, I need to tell the foreground from the background. I have tried imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/bg_removal. Unfortunately this was not good enough. The images can be photographs of pretty much anything, but usually with a blurry background.

I would now like to try liuliu's CCV. Code: https://github.com/liuliu/ccv, Demo: http://liuliu.me/ccv/js/nss/

The demo uses what looks like a json haar cascade to detect faces: https://github.com/liuliu/ccv/blob/unstable/js/face.js

How do I:
1. Convert the xml haar cascade files to be able to be used with CCV
2. Generate the best cascade for my goal (text placement on an image)
3. Find any documentation for CCV

AND, finally, is there a better way to approche this problem?

EDIT: I've asked the border question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559262/programmatically-place-text-in-an-image

Comment: is you goal to improve the contrast and therefore the readability, or is it to avoid writing in objects of interest? If it is contrast, will you always write with the same colour?

Comment: Shouldn't you look for areas of lowest contrast ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with OpenCV, so I'm removing the tag.

Comment: @karlphillip OpenCV is throughout the source code of CCV. From what I can see, CCV is basically offering a javascript front to OpenCV. Does it not makes sense to keep OpenCV as those people who are familiar with OpenCV would most likely be able to answer my questions?

Comment: @QuentinGeissmann The goal is to avoid writing over objects of interest. Obviously, I will also have to tackle contrast (i.e. light text on dark background or visa versa) but, firstly, I need to avoid the objects.

Comment: @dystroy nice idea, I'll try. You would not happen to know the imagemagick command for that?

Comment: @waigani Let's not add tags for technologies that were used for *inspiration*. Right now CCV is not build upon OpenCV nor it depends on it. If you want to add a more helpful tag, add [tag:image-processing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Convert the xml haar cascade files to be able to be used with CCV
> 2. Generate the best cascade for my goal (text placement on an image)
> 3. Find any documentation for CCV

I have no idea about 1) 
(Anyway, which XML files? I guess some from opencv?)
or 3), 
but here is my take on 2)

To make a haar cascade a lá viola&jones, you need a series of small training images that contain *only* your desired objects, for example faces.

One object per image, with as little background as possible, all in the same orientation and size, normalized so they all have the same average brightness and variance in brightness. You will need a lot of training images.

You also need a series of negative training images, same size/brightness etc as the positive examples, that contain only background.

**However, I doubt that this approach will work for you at all:**

Haar filters work by recognizing common rectangular light/dark structures in all your foreground objects. 
So your desired foreground images need to have a common structure.

An example haar filter cascade works like this (extremely simplified):

- is the rectangular region at x1,y1 darker than the region at x2,y2? if no --> not a face, if yes --> continue
- is the region at x3,y3 darker than the region at x4,y4? if no --> not a face --> if yes, continue
- and so on ....

(To find the *position* of a face in a larger image, you execute this filter for *every possible position* in the image. The filter cascade is very fast in rejecting non-faces, so this is doable.)

So your foreground objects need to have a common pattern among them.
For faces, the eye region is darker than the cheek region, and the mouth is darker than the chin, and so on.

The same filter for faces will cease to work if you just rotate the faces.
You cannot build a good filter for both trees and faces, and you definitely cannot build one for general foreground objects. They have no such common structure among them. You would need a separate filter for each possible type of object, so unless your pictures only show a very limited number of types this will not work

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I'm currently experimenting with imagemagick: edge + floodfill to create large areas of unbroken colour and chebyshev kernel to calculate which such area has the largest internal rectangle.

Comment: Marking this as correct answer, as it has helped me to make the decision to focus on imagemagick to find a solution. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569285/finding-largest-rectangle-with-imagemagick-chebyshev