# Finding Largest Rectangle with Imagemagick Chebyshev

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have the following Chebyshev(ed) images:

[image]

[image]

I produced these with the following imagemagick command:

```
convert imagein.jpeg -virtual-pixel black  -morphology Distance Chebyshev -auto-level imageout.jpeg
```

Now, I need to get the x,y position and height/width of the largest rectangle. I have followed instructions here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20269#p81610 and here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#chebyshev. I have tried the following command (which I don't fully understand):

```
convert imagein.jpeg -virtual-pixel black  -morphology Distance Chebyshev \
     \( +clone -auto-level -fill black +opaque white \) \
     -compose multiply -composite -depth 16 txt: |\
  grep -v black
```

This produces the following output (which I also don't fully understand):

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 2272,1704,65535,srgb
1154,437: (43700,43700,43700)  #AAB4AAB4AAB4  srgb(66.6819%,66.6819%,66.6819%)
...
```

What I do understand: 2272,1704 = width/height of image. 1154,437 = x,y pixel position of brightest pixel (center of largest kernel). 43700/100 = pixel radis of kernel (I don't understand why it is repeated three times).

Comment: What do you mean by a rectangle. I mean what corresponds to a rectangle in these images? Please provide some examples. Thereafter it will be easier to find a solution.