# Finding Largest Rectangle opaque with Imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, drawrect, rectangles

I need to extract the biggest (area) rectangle which contains no transparent pixels from a picture.
Here's an exemple (maybe this hand made solution is wrong though):

[image: witness]

[image: rectangle]

I find some link about principles ([in python](https://web.archive.org/web/20190223072159/http://www.drdobbs.com:80/database/the-maximal-rectangle-problem/184410529)) or same topic related issue ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569285/finding-largest-rectangle-with-imagemagick-chebyshev)) but without any answer.

Is it possible to make it with Imagemagick? or any command-line tool on linux?

Comment: Is your rectangle always axis aligned ? The first link is not only about principles, it actually solves your problem. Going with distance transform to solve this is craziness,

Comment: Yes the rectangle is axis aligned (thank god!). At first I looked for an Imagemagick solution, or at least an existing tool. But I currently use a similar python script.

Comment: So did you solve it already or are you still looking for something ?

Comment: It's no more an issue for me even if the solution is not the best I expected, should it be closed ?

Comment: I believe you should include your own solution as an answer and be done with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a command-line based tool to do that, so I 'forked' the version proposed by zed (J.F. Sebastian here) on github : [largest_rectangle script by zed](https://gist.github.com/776423).