# Can Haar Cascade be too accurate to be useful in this situation?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, haar-classifier

I'm making a program to detect shapes from an r/c plane for a competition. I have no real images of the targets, but I do have computer generated examples of them on the rules.

My question is, can I train my program to detect real world objects based on computer generated shapes or should I find a different method to complete this task?

I would like to know before I foolishly generate 5k samples and find them useless in the end.

EDIT: I also don't know the exact color of the objects. If I feed the program samples of varying color, will it be a problem?

Thanks in advance!!

[Edit2: Here's what groups from my school detected in previous years](http://i1090.photobucket.com/albums/i377/jackalsinthecourtyard/ScreenShot2014-02-23at23120AM.png)

As you can see, the detected images are not nearly as flawless as what would appear in real life. If you can suggest a better method, that would help.

Comment: That seems impossible to say without seeing the real and the generated pictures, and even then it depends. Regarding your edit: Most Haar cascades use greyscale images, and normalize the image before recognition. (Also keep in mind that Haar Cascades are not rotational invariant. If you planes can appear at various angles in the image, it will not work)

Comment: Would it be possible to feed different angles of the same shape into the program, or would that cause an increase in false detections? Also let me add some pictures from previous years.

Comment: Training the same cascade with different angles will probably not result in anything usable. A single Haar cascades can only ever work for a specific shape at a specific orientation. (I wrote a rought outline about how a haar cascade works [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10562083/145999)) You would be better off rotating your search image and repeating the detection for each possible angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that the real images will have unique colors with simple geometric shapes then you could probably try to create a normalized Hue-histogram. Use it to train SVM classifier. The benefit of using Hue-histogram is that it will be rotational and scale invariant.

You can take the few precautions in mind:

- Don't forget to remove the illumination affects.
- Sometimes, White and black pixels create some problem in hue-histogram calculation so try to remove them from calculation by considering only those pixel which have `S>0` and `V>0` in S & V channels of HSV image.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being so dense earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to use the real world images because the performance is largely dependent upon training (my personal experience). And why don't you try to use SIFT/SURF descriptors for training to SVM (support vector machine) as SIFT/SURF are scale as well as rotational invariant.

Comment: I don't have real images. From what I've read, SIFT/SURF need real one's too.

Comment: yes...you can get good performance if you do the training with real images

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't have access to the actual targets. The competition has only said that the targets will have high color value and simple geometric shapes. That said, could I train my program using binary images after filtering out low value colors on a thresholded image?

Comment: Yes, i understood your question. Just wanted to say that the performance will be good if training is done at real images. Ok, for your i have updated one more answer.